# Does carbon dioxide naturally freeze on Earth?

Tags: climate

The coldest temperature ever measured at [Vostok Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_Station) is -89.2 °C, well below the sea-level sublimation point of carbon dioxide at -78.5 °C.  However, Vostok Station is well above sea level (3488 m).  Is this still cold enough to get natural dry ice, or is there some other location with a combination of temperature and altitude that can form dry ice?  ([Plateau Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau_Station), for example, is slightly higher and is suspected to be even colder.)

Comment: related https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/are-ice-ages-affected-by-the-freezing-out-of-co2-in-antarctica

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Ice Ages Affected by the Freezing Out of CO2 in Antarctica?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/are-ice-ages-affected-by-the-freezing-out-of-co2-in-antarctica)

Comment: The TL;DR answer to your question is **no**, at least for the last billion or so years.

Comment: The claimed sea level sublimation point of -78.5°C assumes pure carbon dioxide at 1 atmosphere of pressure. This is a valid assumption for a block of dry ice as a thin layer of pure $\text{CO}_2$ forms around the sublimating block. The temperature at which $\text{CO}_2$ undergoes deposition (deposition is the flip side of sublimation) depends solely on the partial pressure of carbon dioxide, which currently is a bit above 40 pascals. It would have to get to -140°C for $\text{CO}_2$ to undergo deposition at sea level, and even colder at altitude. The Earth does not get that cold.

Comment: I made the above a comment as opposed to an answer because the duplicate question has answers that contain this information.